# Laravel extend/include layout if variable == 0

Tags: php, layout, laravel, laravel-blade

Im using laravel 4.0 im tyring to display a layout only if a variable ==0 (just in case a user tries to navigate to the url instead of clicking through) (i know I can redirect instead of extending but this is undesirable for now)

I am trying to get the layout to only extend when the user navigates to the page manually,  noajax is set to true if their is no ajax request being sent when it goes to the function, so if the user where to navigate to the url manually it will still display  the page but extend the layout.

```
@if ($noajax==1)
```

> @extends('layouts.master')
>
> @endif
>
> @section('content')

//controller

```
public function test($id,$model)
{

    if (Request::ajax())
        {
//$foreign_key and $model must be <> null
            if ($id == null || $model == null) {
                $this->render('../Errors/missing_arg', 'error');
                return;
            }

            if($model=="ArtObj")
            {
                $partable = "art_objects";
                $path='img/art-objects/';
            }

            $parid=$id;
            $noajax=0;

        $mediaimgs = Media::where('parent_id' , $id )->where('parent_table', $partable)->paginate(15);
        $response = Response::Json($mediaimgs);
        return View::make('/Admin/manageimage/manage_image',compact('parid','mediaimgs','model','path','noajax'));


        }
        else{

            if($model=="ArtObj")
            {
                $partable = "art_objects";
                $path='img/art-objects/';
            }

            $parid=$id;


        $mediaimgs = Media::where('parent_id' , $id )->where('parent_table', $partable)->paginate(15);
        $response = Response::Json($mediaimgs);
        $noajax = 1;
        return View::make('/Admin/manageimage/manage_image',compact('parid','mediaimgs','model','path','noajax'));
        }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: Ahh sorry well the layout pops up on the page if the user navigates to it, or presses a button which calls an ajax request.

Comment: I don't mean to pick on you or anything but I still don't see what you're trying to ask. I think you're assuming people will read your code and understand what you want but your code has no comments to help others understand what it does. Besides, not everyone will be willing to read through your code to try to understand what you want, so your chances of getting an answer are much higher if you explain as clearly as possible what the problem is or what you want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should use 2 views in controller.

In controller you should use:

```
if ($noajax) {
   return View::make('noajax');
}
else {
   return View::make('ajax');
}
```

In `noajax` view you can extend from any other view and if `noajax` and `ajax` have common code, you should put it in separate file and use `@include` in those both views to include common part of code.